# Error in R dataframe: first column translated

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, row

I've a problem loading a data frame:
I've, shortly, 3 variables: Country, Capital, Population.
When I use

```
data=read.csv(file="data.csv", head=T, sep=",")
```

or

```
data=read.csv(file="data.csv")
```

I obtain
[that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLBtd.png)

the names of the columns are translated, like first column is a row names.
How I can fix that?

Comment: What does the original CSV look like?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585042/why-read-csv-in-r-shift-all-my-data-by-a-column) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302612/column-names-shift-to-left-on-read-table-or-read-csv) questions